# Setting Up Multiple Classes to Represent Real-World Objects

Tags: php, mysql, class, theory

*PHP: If I have a customer class, and the customer can have a car and an invoice, and I want to have separate car and invoice classes, what is the most efficient way of setting them up?*

---

So, I have three different classes:

customer.class.php

customer_car.class.php

customer_invoice.class.php

What's the best way to set up the relationship/initialization between the three classes? A customer can have a car or an invoice. I want to keep the code separated so that its easy to maintain.

```
$customer = new customer();
$car = $customer->newCar();
$invoice = $customer->newInvoice();
```

?

Comment: Now to wait for it to update in the homepage cache.... tick tock...

Comment: @Chacha102 you killed the awesome 'title tells it all' title! ><

Comment: Well the awesome title messed up the CSS on my homepage... so BLEH! :P

Comment: The only problem I find is something the original poster can't find his post afterwards, since it was such a long title, and now its so short....  meh ... Now I've stopped caring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is just an idea as it may be structure differently to reflect your business logics...*

Have 3 seperate classes `customer`, `car` and `invoice`.

`Customers` can can zero to many `cars` to them.

`Customer` can have zero to many `invoices` to them.

An `invoice` may belong to 1 and only 1 `customer` and able to have 1 to many `cars`.

Illustration of a customer class:

```
class Customer 
{
    var $cars = array();
    var $invoices = array();

    function Customer() { }

    function OwnCar($car)
    {
        $cars[] = $car;
    }

    function OwnInvoice($invoice)
    {
        $invoices[] = $invoice;
    }
}
```

Illustration of usage:

```
$customerA = new Customer();
$carA = new Car();
$invoiceA = new Invoice($customerA, array($carA));

$customerA->OwnCar($carA);
$customerA->OwnInvoice($invoiceA);
```

***Note:*** Illustration code is in PHP4, where you may feel free (also recommanded) to develop with PHP5 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

None of the three classes are related at all. so the simple answer is in the question.
Create two variables within the customer class that can hold a car class and an invoice class.

Remember within OOP use the ISA HASA relationships in other words the customer is not a car nor an invoice but the customer has a car and an invoice so in both cases it matches HASA.

The customer ISA person though so you could extend the customer class from a person class.

```
class customer extends person {
    private $invoice; // variable to hold invoice
    private $car;     // variable to hold car

   ...
}
```

DC

Comment: Of course as rockola correctly points out a customer can have multiple of each so you could have arrays holding cars and invoices.

Answer (score 2):

why not

```
$customer = new customer();
$car = new car();
$invoice = new invoice();

$car->SetOwner($customer);
$invoice->SetCustomer($customer);
```

Think about adding a new item, such as `Payment`.  How much additional work is necessary with your approach vs. mine.  This sounds like a homework problem, so I won't spell it out.